# Developing with azure cosmos db emulator where cloud is blocked environment

Tags: java, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-cosmosdb

I'm working on the project which requires Azure Cosmos DB.
However, I cannot connect to Azure cloud in the office because of the security issue. So I thought the emulator is fit for my case.
Is the emulator works on the environment where connecting to Azure is blocked?
Even without Internet?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Cosmos DB emulator is running locally on your machine or in [Docker](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/azure-cosmosdb-emulator/).

This means that you should be able to either install the emulator as a service or pull the docker image and run it in your machine. The emulator won't call anything external while it's running so as long as you have the internet to download the installer or the image you will be able to connect to it.

Read more about the [Azure Cosmos DB emulator here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator).

Comment: Thank you for your comments. However, I faced with this error.               ```Servlet.service() for servlet [com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.sample.ApiServlet] in context with path [/azure-documentdb-java-sample] threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Http client execution failed.```

Comment: It was the problem of the certificates. Thank you.